# How to creating N number of nested for loops

Tags: for-loop, nested-loops

can somebody please help me, to generate N number of nested for loops, it is simple simple if we know the N while we code, but if it is given by the user during the compile time then, how can we generate N number of for loops ?

Comment: Knowing what programming language you're using would be very helpful (one might even say critical), as would a sample of what you have already attempted.

Comment: c++ or python .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is mostly recursive function.
You can make a recursive function `recFun(n : number)` that take a value `n` and make `n` loops that are calling `recFun(n-1)` and stops at 1 or 0.

```
fun recFun(n : number)
   if(n == 0) return ??? ;
   else { 
       for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) 
           recFun(n-1);
   }
```

You can find example in C++ [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-recursion/)

Comment: It's not written in any specific language, it's just pseudo code to show you. You can change the ??? with anything you want your function to do. I edit my answer to add a link to a c++ example.

Comment: OK sir, Thank you.